# Translate string with wp_localize_script()

Tags: wp-localize-script

```
    function s_localization()
{
    $var = [
        'theme_assets_uri' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets',
        'translations' => [
           'view_less' => __('View Less'),
        ]
    ];
    wp_localize_script('aa', 'ddd', $var);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 's_localization');
```

I have the function above. I want to translate a tring from my java script file. When i try to translate 'view less' from my java script file, the word doesn't appear in my string translation in WPML plugin. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using the string properly in the JavaScript? To use the translatable version your _script_ needs to use `ddd.translations.view_less` instead of `'View Less'`.

Comment: Also, your own themes and plugins should use their own text domain: `__( 'View Less', 'my-text-domain' )`.